# Parameter converted from array to string due to ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to fetch data through ajax so i used `$phrase` to translate the the text, but I think due to ajax request `$phrase` converted into string whereas originally it is an array.

As you can see (given in Example:- 1) `var_dump($phrases);` without ajax  showing result in array, but  var_dump($phrases);

inside `if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) === 'xmlhttprequest') {` showing  this string(4) "home" string(4) "home"and I passed $phrases from  controllers index() to subcategory($phrases)

so help me to fix it

Example:- 1

```
array(3140) { ["absolutely"]=> string(23) "बिल्कुल" ["achieve"]=> string(58) "प्राप्त करना" }
```

controllers

```
class Lispo extends BaseController {
    public function index() {
        $commonData = $this->getCommonData();

       //<<>>[[ Access the $phrase and $selectedLanguage variable from the common data  ]]<<>>//
       $phrases = $commonData['phrase'];
  
       $this->subcategory($phrases);

}//other code here


  public function subcategory($phrases) {
               
               if (isset($_POST['csrf_token']) && CSRFHelper::verifyCsrfToken($_POST['csrf_token'])) {
                   require_once 'app/models/category.class.php';
                   require_once 'app/libs/cryptor.class.php';
                   $crypt = new Cryptor();
                   $categoryModel = new Category();
                   $translator = new TextTranslator($phrases);
                   $id = trim($_POST['dataId']);
                   $results = $categoryModel->getCategoriesWithSubcategories($id);
                   $html = '';
              
                   foreach ($results as $subcategory) {
                       // Add condition for status 0
                       $statusClass = ($subcategory->status == 0) ? 'fa-solid fa-lock' : 'bi bi-chevron-right';
                       $disableClass = ($subcategory->status == 0) ? 'disable-click' : '';
                       $subid = $crypt->encryptId($subcategory->catID);
                       $subcategoryName = $translator->translateText($subcategory->category);
                       $html .= '<div class="s_cali s_vrEfW5 ' . $disableClass . '" role="button" data-id="' . $subid . '"><span class="s_evrEOf">' . $subcategoryName . '</span><span class="' . $statusClass . '"></span></div>';
                   }
           
                   // Instead of echo json_encode($html);
                   echo json_encode(['success' => true, 'html' => $html]);
               }
             
           }
    }
```

AJAX

```
$(document).on("click", ".s_zpSpH4", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var csrf_token = $(".csrf_token").val();
  var dataId = $(this).data("id");

  var clickedElement = $(this);  // Store the reference to the clicked element

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: BASEURL + "lispo/subcategory",
    data: { csrf_token: csrf_token, dataId: dataId },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.success) {
        clickedElement.hide();  // Use the stored reference to hide the clicked element
        $('.s_qeV3Mr').html(data.html);
      } else {
        console.log(data.error);
      }
    },
    error: function (error) {
      // Handle errors if any
      console.error("AJAX error:", error);
      console.log(error.responseText);
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: `dataType: 'json',` did you tell your ajax you are working with a json?

Comment: @ezw yes i tried, issue is  $phrase is conveted from array to string , how to fix that  in subCategory() function

Comment: The php should return the json_encode, not echo it

Comment: @ezw then how will i get response in ajax?

Comment: Sorry, I have `die(json_encode($jsonReply))` in my php. Although what you have is correct

Comment: Maybe all you need to do now is clearing the cache

Comment: As an aside, I recommend using `$html .= sprintf(... your stuff ..);` to eliminate the single-use variables and messy concatenation.

Comment: @mickmackusa I noticed that when i pass `$this->subcategory($phrases);` from index function to  `public function subcategory($phrases)` then it is converted into string originally it should be array. I noticed its happening due to ajax request, how can fix it?

Comment: Your javascript is making a POST request to the `subcategory()` method via `BASEURL + "lispo/subcategory"`. That method expects a parameter, but you are not giving it one. Do you have error reporting turned on? Do you mean to call `index()` instead?

Comment: @mickmackusa can't we achieve this without passing the parameter, by directly directly passing through index function to subcategory($phrases)

Comment: @Raj What exactly is stopping you from simply calling `index()`?  It unconditionally calls `subcategory()` anyhow. Personally, I don't like that your "helper method" is `public` (instead of `private`) and that `echo`s data instead of returning data to the method that called it.  Is this application built on a particular framework?